# Unable to resize windows on split full screen in MacOS Mojave when using external monitor

Tags: display, mojave, fullscreen

I'm running MacOS Mojave on a 13" Macbook pro with a 4K external monitor (scaled to 2560 x 1440).

When running two apps in split full screen mode it won't let me reposition the "split" which controls the share of the screen of the two apps by grabbing the vertical bar.

This behaviour can be seem in [this screen recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQeF0.jpg).

Any ideas on how to solve this? Or is this just a bug that needs fixing?

Comment: what apps are you running ?

Comment: I do not see you moving the separator bar in the middle of the screen

Comment: @Buscar웃 in this case firefox and iterm2, but the issue happens regardless of the apps used. I'm not moving the separator bar because it wont let me. When clicking and dragging it the bar remains.

Comment: yes now I see it

Comment: I can confirm this still an issue on macOS Mojave 10.14.1.

Comment: I took the liberty of creating a discussion in macOS Mojave community about this: https://discussions.apple.com/message/34106080

Comment: macOS Mojave 10.14.3 and this issue still remains.

Comment: just updated to macOs Mojave 10.14.5 from High Sierra. Now I'm here ‍♂️

Comment: Still present in 10.14.6.  How do we tell Apple!?  Seems crazy for a bug this obvious to be present for so long.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is fixed in Catalina?

Answer (score 68):

WORKAROUND:
Read somewhere that to get (temporarily) the resizing bar, you drag one of the split windows by the title to the other side of the monitor. The bar will remain for a while. Resize, and if needed, switch back the windows. It has been working for me on an external LG monitor in Mojave.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this answer works consistently (especially with multiple displays and splits). Thanks!

Comment: can also confirm this works

Comment: I'm using an extended display. If my screens' orientations are LEFT/RIGHT, the above suggestion for resizing works. However, if my screens' orientations are TOP/BOTTOM, then it doesn't work. This is true only for my extended display and not for the built-in monitor.

Answer (score 3):

I found that if you simply click the title bar you'll be able to drag the windows after, for a few seconds.

I believe that this is intentional to prevent changes to the screen split by mistake.

So it's possible that this is by design.

Comment: Still not fixed, but thank goodness the WORKAROUND solution above works!

Comment: Note that you get only once chance to resize it on hover. If you missed and the second hover won't change the cursor. You have to do click again.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue… I’m working around it by resizing the windows in split view on the MacBook screen and only then dragging them to the external monitor, but this "solution" is obviously far from perfect :/ Hope they fix this soon.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: When putting things into full screen, don't put anything full screen instead hold the green expand button on the top left, wait until a side turns blue, than select side, select your second app, now you have a bar in the middle you can drag left/right.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- split the window in your computer screen (desktop 1)
- resize them as you want
- Zoom out (using your 4 fingers on the pad) to see all the desktops (windows).
- pick, drag your window from your computer and drop it to the external monitor

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me....

I got out of it by doing a three finger swipe up the mousepad
This takes you to a view where you can see all spaces at once
Then hover over the space with the expanded app - it will give you an option to minimize it. Click that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an annoying bug that I have reported to apple numerous times.

The best workaround I have found is to move your mouse to the top of the screen to bring down the title bar, and then click on the title bar.

You have to play around and try the title bar for each window. One of them will bring up the resizing indicator temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed broken in Mojave `10.14.6`.  Confirmed mostly-fixed in Catalina `10.15.3`.   I say mostly-fixed, because the slider is only adjustable if the *right side* has focus.  If the *left side* has focus, then you still can't resize the slider.  But it's a very easy workaround, which was not possible until Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it only works when the right window is active. no idea why that is the case, but I always have to select the right one, ever since High Sierra or at least Catalina.