# Is there a way to re-size the XQuartz window?

Tags: display, fullscreen, xquartz

I am using a Macbook Pro (16-inch 2019, OSX 12.6.5) with X2go to connect to a remote Linux unit. When I connect my Macbook to a secondary display, using the "extended display mode", XQuartz opens an extremely wide window, which roughly covers the size of my two combined displays (main and extended). I am not able to re-size this XQuartz window, nor have I found any setting to put a limit to/regulate the dimensions.
I have read this thread ([Unable to resize windows on split full screen in MacOS Mojave when using external monitor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/340555/499799)) but apparently, I am not able to split the screen with another app because XQuartz immediately hides its window.
Do you have hints/suggestions?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a guess, but resizing is not possible because the size of the window has to be proportional to the resolution of what the Xserver is using.

Comment: WHat happens with local x apps like xterm or xeyes?

Answer (score -1):

Apple menu > System Settings, then click Displays in the sidebar, then change resolution from Default to More Space.

Comment: Not sure if you understood the question here. Changing the resolution doesn't resize the window, it resizes the whole system.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/341590)